# Elliptic curve confusion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am confused by some lecture I heard.
It was stated that the elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ would be a subset of the elliptic curve over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.
But isn't it exactly the other way arround that $ E(\mathbb{F}_{q}) \subset E(\mathbb{F}_{q^k})$ for some $k\geq 1$?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Can you link to the lecture you heard or some reference material, its hard to know what the lecture was trying to say. But yes you are right the containment of points of a variety goes the way you stated it.

Comment: A possibility that occurs to me is that may be the intended statement should read: *For all $k$ we have $E(\Bbb{F}_{q^k})\subset E(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q})$.* In other words, it would refer to *an algebraic closure* of $\Bbb{F}_q$. This is needed to really get *a curve* as opposed to *a finite collection of points*. Mind you, there are many ways of achieving that, but referring to an algebraic closure is common.